# What's with the sort of repetitive output and how does it differentiate between the number of iterations and the Ascii code?

Tags: c++

After running the following code and entering A, this is my output:

```
char   0 is character A with ascii code 65
char   1 is character 
 with ascii code 10
```

I have two questions about this output:

1. Why is the output

   ```
   char 0 is character A with ascii code 65
   ```

   and not

   ```
   char 65 is character A with ascii code 0
   ```

How does the program know that the first "%3d" is associated with the number of iterations (I think) and the second "%d" is associated with the Ascii value?
"%c" is a character data type so it prints A, but there is nothing to  differentiate between the "%d" except for maybe the 3 in front of the first "%3d" (but doesn't that just mean number of positions including the decimal point?

2. Where does

   ```
   char 1 is character 
    with ascii code 10
   ```

come from?  Does it have to do with the `c,c` part in the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
    int c,n=0;
    while ((c=getchar()) !='Q' )
    printf ("char %3d is character %c with ascii code %d\n", n++, c,c);
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're asking how [variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) work. Or perhaps this is [about `printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for *printf format specifiers*?

Comment: Are you asking about the second and fourth outputs?  They're because `getchar` is reading the newline character you entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format specifiers are in the same order as the arguments to `printf`, so "%3d" corresponds to the second argument to `printf`, `%c` corresponds to the third argument, and "%d" corresponds to the fourth.  In general, the n+1st argument to `printf` corresponds to the nth format specifier.

In the call `printf("cahr %3d is character %c with ascii code %d\n", n++, c, c)`, "%3d" corresponds to the argument `n++`, "%c" corresponds to `c`, and "%d" corresponds to the second `c`.

The reason for the

```
char 1 is character 
 with ascii code 10
```

Line is that you are entering a newline character when you press the enter key.

Comment: Ooooh thank you so much!  understand it now! I also went and googled what arguments and parameters are. I read that arguments can be thought of as values assigned to the temporary variable and parameters are placeholders for arguments. Makes sense!

Comment: And oooh, OK! I understand now the reason it went on a new line. I wonder why it put 'with ascii code 10' on a new line instead of 'is character' on a newline though...

Comment: Because `c` is the newline character in that iteration of the loop, the "%c" format specifier is replaced with a newline character in the string printed.

Comment: Oooh ok I see :) Thank you so much!